# What unusual characters in addition to $ are allowed in JavaScript identifiers?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I want a variable like $ that is sort of special, but I'm already using jQuery, so $ is taken.

Comment: You could always run JQuery in compatibility mode and type in jQuery instead of $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a special variable like $ but $ is already taken by jQuery, why not use something that starts with $, like $a or similar? Just make sure it's one that jQuery doesn't also define.

Comment: jQuery can handle `$` conflicts, so `$` could be just fine. After all, jQuery borrowed the dollar from prototype.js

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, older javascript supports letters, numbers, underscores, and $ in identifiers.  In javascript 1.5 and later you can use Unicode characters, but that would be a very bad idea as they can be a pain to enter into most editors, and certainly aren't something you would want to have to type very often.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Variables)

Comment: That's the source I was looking at. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The one I like it best:

```
λ = Function;
```

Unfortunately it's very difficult to type it.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore is the only one I can think of. You can put a few together like `_$_`.

Starting in JavaScript 1.5, you can use Unicode such as å.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype uses [$](http://prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar) and a [$$](http://prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar).  If you're using jQuery, you could use $$.  However, unless its really well documented, this may be a bad idea--especially if someone else has to maintain this code after you've moved on.